# FullStack iPad App

Tags: app, ipad

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

FullStack provides read only access to the following Stack Exchange sites: Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, and Ask Ubuntu. Currently users can browse through all questions with easy navigation through different categories including Active, Featured, Hot, New, and Unanswered- just to name a few. Search capabilities also exist to find and locate a particular question that you may have. There is also support for bookmarking questions to provide easy and quick access to those questions that are particularly interesting to you. Please note that currently the Stack Exchange sites to not provide any write capabilities but as soon as version 2 of their API is released we will integrate as fast as humanly possible. Lastly, please note that we are not affiliated with Stack Exchange in any way except for the fact that this application uses their awesome API.

#### License

You can find the app through iTunes simply by searching for FullStack under the iPad section.

#### Download

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fullstack/id420859244?mt=8&ls=1#

#### Platform

The Apple iPad

### Contact

Andreas Sandberg

### Code

Built using the Titanium SDK.

Comment: I inserted the screenshot image for you. If you prefer the link, just let me know, and I'll roll back the edit.